# Is it possible to specify multiple home pages for the default android browser?

Tags: browser, stock-browser

That is, I want my browser to start with two tabs open, set to two different URLs.
I have tried putting "google.com | facebook.com" into the URL but that does not seem to achieve the intended effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No, it's not possible.**

How did I get such result? As always I started to google this possibility but found nothing interesting. So I decided to check [Android Browser source code](http://omapzoom.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Browser.git;a=summary). If you want you can download it by typing in console:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Browser
```

After 5-10 minutes (I'm not new in programming) of looking repository I found 2 facts:

1) The homepage is saved as one [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) (Java type).

2) The homepage is opening by calling this function (in `Controller.java`):

```
@Override
public Tab openTabToHomePage() {
    return openTab(mSettings.getHomePage(), false, true, false);
}
```

So as you see (If you know programming a bit) it returns **one tab**, not several (like `List<Tab>`).

Comment: Kudos for taking the time to read the source. I should have done that but wasn't familiar with Android source tree to quickly find the browser code.